# Mocking Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

I want to implements tests in Spring Boot (Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE), so I am checking this example

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

but not able to find the given method anywhere in this package

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bottom of the article there is a link to the github repo with the full source of the [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.M2/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-test/src/test/java/sample/test/web/UserVehicleControllerTests.java). There you can see the following line:

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
```